# Changing Windows+Printscreen to just Printscreen

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to save screen shot of the screen to folder. I know this can be done with Windows+Printscreen key in Windows. I want to silently (without any popup) save the screenshot to folder with just Printscreen key, that is without requiring to hit Windows button. Is it possible to do so throught some configuration or using some tool?

Comment: Autohotkey perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will map PrintScreen to Windows+PrintScreen :

```
PrintScreen::Send, #{PrintScreen}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)